# Windows: Booting from one drive to load another

Tags: windows-10

I recently purchased a windows 10 tablet with a 32gb internal flash storage and a pcie micro sdcard reader. I have run out of space on my internal flash, so I cloned my flash storage to a 128gb micro sd card to boot from. However because the micro sd card reader is pcie it isn'tdetected by the bios. Is there a way to have a boot manager on the flash storage load pcie drivers and boot into the sd card?p